# Por que minhas webfonts só funcionam com o Chrome?

Tags: css3, twitter-bootstrap, css-font-face

Estou a criar um website através de um *child theme* do Shoestrap, baseado em Bootstrap. Quando uso as webfonts elas apenas funcionam no Chrome.

O que estou a fazer mal?

O meu CSS é este

```css
@font-face {
   font-family: 'open_sansitalic';
   src: url('assets/fonts/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.eot');
   src: url('assets/fonts/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('assets/fonts/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('assets/fonts/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('assets/fonts/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.svg#open_sansitalic') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}

h1 { font-family: 'open_sansitalic' sans-serif;  font-size: 40pt; line-height: 50pt; color: #f68934; }
```

Comment: Já tentou mudar o CSS do ```h1``` para: ```font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;``` e adicionar ```font-style:italic;```?

Comment: isso não corresponde às "font-family" declaradas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente utilizar fonts do Google, a [Open Sans está disponível nele](http://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace%3aquickUse/Family%3aOpen+Sans).

Escolhas os estilos que você quer e depois é só adicionar no seu código HTML:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

E para usar no CSS:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

Com isso você evita requisições no seu servidor também.

Sobre performance no front-end, de uma lida em: http://browserdiet.com/pt/

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 5):

Verifique se os outros arquivos de fonte podem ser acessados diretamente pelo navegador, seu servidor pode estar com problemas de falta de declaração de **mime-type**.
Pode ser que seja o arquivo **.htaccess** que esteja bloqueando o acesso aos arquivos de fontes.

As extensões são: *.svg, *.woff, *.ttf e *.eot

Comment: Já experimentei colocar o codigo: 
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|woff|ttf)$">
  SetEnvIf Origin »
    "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(domain1\.org|domain\.com)$" origin_is=$0
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
</FilesMatch> e não resultou

Comment: Entretanto resolvi usar google fonts, e isso resultou. Noutros projectos, com outras fontes não sei se isso será viável. Eu tenho estado a trabalhar no localhost

Answer (score 1):

Muitas vezes isso acontece devido a má renderização dos arquivos na hora que são gerados. Isso já aconteceu muitas vezes comigo.

Tente renderizar nesse site: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator, o melhor na minha opnião.

Utilizo essa fonte no site da empresa onde trabalho, veja: http://www.lecom.com.br (google fonts)

O amigo acima está certo, existe no google fonts, pesquisa lá.

Answer (score 1):

coloca uma virgula depois do nome da web fonte

```
ex: font-family: 'open_sansitalic', sans-serif;  font-size: 40pt; line-height: 50pt; color: #f68934;
```

Acho que isso resolve.